# How to convert jquery ajax to native javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

here is my ajaxHandler i want to convert this to native javascript i.e 
using XMLHttpRequest but i am unable to understand how to convert.`

```js
ajaxHandler = {
  defaultAttributes: {
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'index.php/request',
    datatype: 'json',
    data: {},
    success: null,
    error: function(data) {
      errorHandler.showError('An Error occurred while trying to retreive your requested data, Please try again...');
    },
    timeout: function() {
      errorHandler.showError('The request has been timed out, Please check your Internet connection and try again...');
    }
  },
  sendRequest: function(attributes) {
    Paper.giffyLoading.style.display = 'block';
    if (!attributes.nopopup) {
      if (attributes.loadmsg) {
        Controllers.AnimationController.createProgressBarScreen(attributes.loadmsg);
        attributes.loadmsg = null;
      }
    }
    $.ajax(attributes);
  }
}
```

i have try to convert the above code like this

```js
XMLRequestDefaultHandler = function() {
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.open('GET', 'index.php/request', true);
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4 || xmlHttp.status === 200) {

    } else {
      errorHandler.showError('An Error occurred while trying to retreive your requested data, Please try again...');


    }
  };
  xmlHttp.send(null);

}
```

Comment: why do you even want to?

Comment: Read up on `XMLHttpRequest`: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest1/).

Comment: Also read about jqueery AJAX - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ - understand that and the previous link, and you'll be on your way very quickly

Comment: i have try to change but not working

Comment: i want that some one help me to convert this to native js

Comment: @MuhammadAsifJaved You can extract function of jquery.

Comment: No, we wouldn't help you to write your code. What you could do is show us your attempts at doing so, and what have went wrong—we can then take it from there. If you want somebody to write everything for you, be prepared to pay for a service.

Comment: @Terry i have update the post with my attempt

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I extracted ajax function of Jquery, to work without jquery.

And replace `$.ajax(attributes);` to `ajax(attributes);`

### JQuery's ajax function, without JQuery :

```
function ajax(option) { // $.ajax(...) without jquery.
    if (typeof(option.url) == "undefined") {
        try {
            option.url = location.href;
        } catch(e) {
            var ajaxLocation;
            ajaxLocation = document.createElement("a");
            ajaxLocation.href = "";
            option.url = ajaxLocation.href;
        }
    }
    if (typeof(option.type) == "undefined") {
        option.type = "GET";
    }
    if (typeof(option.data) == "undefined") {
        option.data = null;
    } else {
        var data = "";
        for (var x in option.data) {
            if (data != "") {
                data += "&";
            }
            data += encodeURIComponent(x)+"="+encodeURIComponent(option.data[x]);
        };
        option.data = data;
    }
    if (typeof(option.statusCode) == "undefined") { // 4
        option.statusCode = {};
    }
    if (typeof(option.beforeSend) == "undefined") { // 1
        option.beforeSend = function () {};
    }
    if (typeof(option.success) == "undefined") { // 4 et sans erreur
        option.success = function () {};
    }
    if (typeof(option.error) == "undefined") { // 4 et avec erreur
        option.error = function () {};
    }
    if (typeof(option.complete) == "undefined") { // 4
        option.complete = function () {};
    }
    typeof(option.statusCode["404"]);

    var xhr = null;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest || window.ActiveXObject) {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) { try { xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); } catch(e) { xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); } }
        else { xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
    } else { alert("Votre navigateur ne supporte pas l'objet XMLHTTPRequest..."); return null; }

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 1) {
            option.beforeSend();
        }
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            option.complete(xhr, xhr.status);
            if (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0) {
                option.success(xhr.responseText);
            } else {
                option.error(xhr.status);
                if (typeof(option.statusCode[xhr.status]) != "undefined") {
                    option.statusCode[xhr.status]();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    if (option.type == "POST") {
        xhr.open(option.type, option.url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
        xhr.send(option.data);
    } else {
        xhr.open(option.type, option.url+option.data, true);
        xhr.send(null);
    }

}
```

Comment: this is working fine when i send 'GET' and 'POST' request please update how i will send the query string to 'GET' method

Comment: Set data of *attributes* object like this : `data: { string: "My string" },`

Comment: Doesn't work with JSON payloads because of the fixed content-type.

Comment: I'd remove `|| xhr.status ==0` from the success function as that's the default status, the status returned on a timeout, the error status for some browsers. Add something like this: `xhr.ontimeout = function(){};` instead. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/status)

Comment: window.fetch is maybe better now: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch