# Python Selenium modify and run script

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to test a script on a website through python using the Selenium library.
The only thing is that I have to modify the script first by removing a part of the script before running it.
Below is the script and the part I would like to remove.

**Part to remove**

```
 //alert(data);
                if(data === 'BAD'){
                    $('.win_tr').show();
                    $('.winText').html('<img src="/images/icons/cross.png" /> Je hebt niet genoeg spins om aan het geluksrad te draaien!');
                    wheelSpinning = false;          // Reset to false to power buttons and spin can be clicked again.
```

**Script**

```
<script>
// Create new wheel object specifying the parameters at creation time.
var theWheel = new Winwheel({
    'numSegments'  : 12,     // Specify number of segments.
    'outerRadius'  : 212,   // Set outer radius so wheel fits inside the background.
    'textFontSize' : 18,    // Set font size as desired.
    'textDirection'   : 'reversed',
    'segments'     :        // Define segments including colour and text.
    [
       {'fillStyle' : '#eae56f', 'prize' : '0', 'text' : '10 Eerpunten'},
       {'fillStyle' : '#89f26e', 'prize' : '1', 'text' : '10 Credits'},
       {'fillStyle' : '#7de6ef', 'prize' : '2', 'text' : '250 Hoeren'},
       {'fillStyle' : '#e7706f', 'prize' : '3', 'text' : '$10.000.000'},
       {'fillStyle' : '#eae56f', 'prize' : '4', 'text' : 'Geen Prijs'},
       {'fillStyle' : '#89f26e', 'prize' : '5', 'text' : '50 Eerpunten'},
       {'fillStyle' : '#7de6ef', 'prize' : '6', 'text' : '50 Credits'},
       {'fillStyle' : '#e7706f', 'prize' : '7', 'text' : '$25.000.000'},
        {'fillStyle' : '#eae56f', 'prize' : '0', 'text' : '250 Hoeren'},
        {'fillStyle' : '#89f26e', 'prize' : '1', 'text' : 'Geen Prijs'},
        {'fillStyle' : '#7de6ef', 'prize' : '2', 'text' : '500 Hoeren'},
        {'fillStyle' : '#e7706f', 'prize' : '3', 'text' : '1000 Hoeren'}
    ],
    'animation' :           // Specify the animation to use.
    {
        'type'     : 'spinToStop',
        'duration' : 5,     // Duration in seconds.
        'spins'    : 8,     // Number of complete spins.
        'callbackFinished' : 'alertPrize()'
    }
});

// Vars used by the code in this page to do power controls.
var wheelPower    = 0;
var wheelSpinning = false;

// -------------------------------------------------------
// Function to handle the onClick on the power buttons.
// -------------------------------------------------------
function powerSelected(powerLevel)
{
    // Ensure that power can't be changed while wheel is spinning.
    if (wheelSpinning == false)
    {
        // Reset all to grey incase this is not the first time the user has selected the power.
        document.getElementById('pw1').className = "";
        document.getElementById('pw2').className = "";
        document.getElementById('pw3').className = "";

        // Now light up all cells below-and-including the one selected by changing the class.
        if (powerLevel >= 1)
        {
            document.getElementById('pw1').className = "pw1";
        }

        if (powerLevel >= 2)
        {
            document.getElementById('pw2').className = "pw2";
        }

        if (powerLevel >= 3)
        {
            document.getElementById('pw3').className = "pw3";
        }

        // Set wheelPower var used when spin button is clicked.
        wheelPower = powerLevel;

        // Light up the spin button by changing it's source image and adding a clickable class to it.
        document.getElementById('spin_button').src = "spin_on.png";
        document.getElementById('spin_button').className = "clickable";
    }
}

// -------------------------------------------------------
// Click handler for spin button.
// -------------------------------------------------------
function startSpin()
{
    // Ensure that spinning can't be clicked again while already running.
    if (wheelSpinning == false)
    {
        // Based on the power level selected adjust the number of spins for the wheel, the more times is has
        // to rotate with the duration of the animation the quicker the wheel spins.
        if (wheelPower == 1)
        {
            theWheel.animation.spins = 3;
        }
        else if (wheelPower == 2)
        {
            theWheel.animation.spins = 8;
        }
        else if (wheelPower == 3)
        {
            theWheel.animation.spins = 15;
        }

        // Disable the spin button so can't click again while wheel is spinning.
        document.getElementById('spin_button').src       = "spin_off.png";
        document.getElementById('spin_button').className = "";

        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax/wheeloffortune.php?getnumber',
            type: 'post',
            data: {},
            dataTupe: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                //alert(data);
                if(data === 'BAD'){
                    $('.win_tr').show();
                    $('.winText').html('<img src="/images/icons/cross.png" /> Je hebt niet genoeg spins om aan het geluksrad te draaien!');
                    wheelSpinning = false;          // Reset to false to power buttons and spin can be clicked again.
                }else{
                    resetWheel();
                    var stopAt = (data);

                    // alert(data);
                    theWheel.animation.stopAngle = stopAt;

                    // Begin the spin animation by calling startAnimation on the wheel object.
                    theWheel.startAnimation();

                    // Set to true so that power can't be changed and spin button re-enabled during
                    // the current animation. The user will have to reset before spinning again.
                    wheelSpinning = true;

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/ajax/wheeloffortune.php',
                        type: 'post',
                        data: {start_spin:true},
                        dataTupe: 'json',
                        success: function(data) {

                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                            // alert('Something went wrong');
                            $('.win_tr').show();
                            $('.winText').html('<img src="/images/icons/cross.png" /> Er is iets fout gegaan!');
                            wheelSpinning = false;          // Reset to false to power buttons and spin can be clicked again.
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                // alert('Something went wrong');
                $('.win_tr').show();
                $('.winText').html('<img src="/images/icons/cross.png" /> Er is iets fout gegaan!');
                wheelSpinning = false;          // Reset to false to power buttons and spin can be clicked again.
            }
        });
    }
}

// -------------------------------------------------------
// Function for reset button.
// -------------------------------------------------------
function resetWheel()
{
    theWheel.stopAnimation(false);  // Stop the animation, false as param so does not call callback function.
    theWheel.rotationAngle = 0;     // Re-set the wheel angle to 0 degrees.
    theWheel.draw();                // Call draw to render changes to the wheel.

    // document.getElementById('pw1').className = "";  // Remove all colours from the power level indicators.
    // document.getElementById('pw2').className = "";
    // document.getElementById('pw3').className = "";
}

// -------------------------------------------------------
// Called when the spin animation has finished by the callback feature of the wheel because I specified callback in the parameters.
// -------------------------------------------------------
function alertPrize()
{
    // Get the segment indicated by the pointer on the wheel background which is at 0 degrees.
    var winningSegment = theWheel.getIndicatedSegment();

    // Do basic alert of the segment text. You would probably want to do something more interesting with this information.
    // alert("You have won " + winningSegment.text);

    var winText = winningSegment.text;
    var winPrize = winningSegment.prize;

    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/wheeloffortune.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {text:winText, prize_won:winPrize},
        dataTupe: 'json',
        success: function(data) {

            var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

            // Show whole array
            var data2 = JSON.stringify(data);
            // console.log(data2);

            // De win tekst
            var winText = data['tekst'];
            var status = data['status'];
            var likes2 = data['prize'];

            var new_spins = $('.spins').text() - 1;
            if(new_spins < 0) {
                new_spins = 0;
            }
            $('.spins').html(new_spins);

            $('.win_tr').show();
            if(status = 'OK' && winText !== 'BAD') {
                $('.winText').html('<img src="/images/icons/tick.png" /> ' + winText + '');
            }else{
                $('.winText').html('<img src="/images/icons/cross.png" /> Er is iets fout gegaan!');
            }
            wheelSpinning = false;          // Reset to false to power buttons and spin can be clicked again.
        },
        error: function (data) {
            //alert('Something went wrong');
            $('.win_tr').show();
            $('.winText').html('<img src="/images/icons/cross.png" /> Er is iets fout gegaan!');
            wheelSpinning = false;          // Reset to false to power buttons and spin can be clicked again.
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have yet to see a selenium/python script that executes an ajax call. You may have to go through that line by line and convert it to python.

Comment: @Jortega Is there another way than selenium to get the same result?

Comment: ajax is actually just javascript so you could convert the ajax calls to javascript. See this example.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33196546/how-to-convert-jquery-ajax-to-native-javascript