# to do the functionality of jquery `success` function by pure js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.ajax({
            success: function (returns) {
                if (returns)
                    alert("returned successfully");
            }
        });
```

how can I turn this jquery function to pure js?I'm new in js by the way!

Comment: Look into the Fetch API and Promises! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp

Comment: I already took a look at `fetch` but as mentioned I'm new and could not do it correctly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert jquery ajax to native javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33196546/how-to-convert-jquery-ajax-to-native-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

On your *XMLHttpRequest* object add a listener on `onreadystatechange` :

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)) {
    option.success(xhr.responseText)
  }
}
```